# vb.net console readline using specific encoding

Tags: .net, vb.net, encoding, console

How do I set the encoding by which a .NET console application reads an input file?

I have a UTF16 file and when I call `Console.ReadLine` it's clear that the encoding wasn't properly observed.  The string coming from that call looks bad.

Sublime Text 2 reports that the files is in encoded as:

```
UTF-16 LE with BOM
```

Here's the code:

```
    pstrLine = Console.ReadLine() //bad line here

    Do
        pactHandler(pstrLine)
        pstrLine = Console.ReadLine()
    Loop Until pstrLine Is Nothing
```

A line comes back and I can read it, but it's not quite right.  Every character seems to have a space between it.  And the line starts with an unprintable character.

When I look at the input file it looks like:

```
MY DATA IS HERE
```

When it comes in via `ReadLine`:

```
$M Y  D A T A  I S  H E R E
```

`$` represents and unprintable character which looks like a block.

Comment: I'm guessing you are using input redirection.  Don't do that, you cannot reliably detect text encoding with that.  Actually open the file with StreamReader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`System.Console`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143369.aspx) class has a property for [`InputEncoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.inputencoding.aspx) and `OutputEncoding`.

Supply a value for these properties with a [`UnicodeEncoding` object whose constructor you provide two bools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/984ebfcy.aspx): big endian and byte order mark.

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO

Dim Utf16LeBom = New UnicodeEncoding(False, True)
Console.InputEncoding = Utf16LeBom
Console.OutputEncoding = Utf16LeBom
Console.ReadLine()
```

If you go on to modify your code to read from a stream using `StreamReader`, you can use the same `UnicodeEncoding` object.

Comment: Your time and effort is much appreciated.  Thank you.